# python 3.6 string/unicode error

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am using python 3.6 on a Windows 10 computer and I have problem with strings.

when I type:

```
path2 = "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/dataTestPython"
test="‪test_pilot2.0.1.vhdr"
print(path2+os.path.sep+test)
```

I get this error:

```
 'C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/dataTestPython\\\u202atest_pilot2.0.1.vhdr'
```

I don't get why it add u"202a at the beginning of variable test.

sometimes I have to add r before opening "", I don't understand why but sometimes it solves a "Unicode" missunderstanding in the string path2 but it doesn't work with the variable test.

I never had this kind of problem and I have used python 2.7 and 3.5 on linux and Windows computer.
it's the first time I try python 3.6.

I tried to do a .py with :

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

at the beginning of the file but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try `print(repr(test))` and you'll see that the `\u202a` character is actually part of your input.

Comment: `\u202a` is a Unicode control character used when writing bidirectional text (some parts are written from left-to-right, and some parts from right-to-left). It happens, for instance, if the native language of your OS is written from right-to-left (e.g. Hebrew or Arabic). It this the case for you?

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. Somehow you've gotten the non-spacing unicode character marking left-to-right text. You can use the name for writing/reading files but if you had another `test2` that was the same name without the marker, it doesn't compare the same. I don't know how to normalize a file system name in python. Hope someone answers this!

Comment: Using `os.listdir` on my linux ext4 file system, that character is part of the file system name, and a normalized name with the character stripped doesn't find the file. So, ext4 doesn't normalize either. I see I have some reading ahead of me...

Comment: BTW, you should use `os.path.join()`

Comment: yes I will use os.path.join() but I had the same problem with it, then I tried witout it and that is what I post. I have seen that \u202a is unicode for right-to-left but I didn't understood what that mean. I didn't thought about hebrew/arabic languages. I am not administrator on this computer, the user account is in swiss french. the keyboard is swiss (qwertz).

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes but why ? I can't find any solution ... I just got a second computer doing that. (installed by the same "client")

Comment: `print(repr(test))` yields `'\u202atest_pilot2.0.1.vhdr'`…